# Error:inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model `About`:

```
class About(models.Model):
    displayname=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email=models.EmailField(max_length=70)
    website=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    photo=models.FileField(upload_to='uploaded_image')
    des=models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

It's giving me the error: 
`Error:inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation`
 in this line:

```
email=models.EmailField(max_length=70)
```

Comment: So, what don't you understand about the error? Don't mix spaces and tabs. In fact, don't use tabs at all.

Answer (score 0):

Indentation error means Most likely you're mixing tabs with spaces - use one or the other for your indenting... preferably spaces. 
Or,First locate the line on which this error occurs. Delete the line entirely. Go to the end of the preceding line and then press enter. Now enter the line.